# How to modify or read a mutable vector passed as an argument in a function?

Tags: haskell, vector, monads, mutable

```
  test :: VM.MVector s Int -> Int
  test x = runST $ do
    a <- return x
    VM.read a 0 -- Type error
```

I am trying to figure out how to not put everything inside a ST monad into a single function. If I tried to modify `x` or return a value from it, the compiler would complain about the state part of the mutable vector not matching up.

Would operating on passed mutable vectors be possible in Haskell or do I have to freeze them into the immutable counterparts before doing anything on them?

Edit:

Here is the actual error.

```
Couldn't match type `s1' with `s'
  `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: ST s1 Int at rjb.hs:17:12
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for test :: VM.MVector s Int -> Int
      at rjb.hs:16:11
Expected type: VM.MVector
                 (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (ST s1)) Int
  Actual type: VM.MVector s Int
Relevant bindings include
  a :: VM.MVector s Int (bound at rjb.hs:18:5)
  x :: VM.MVector s Int (bound at rjb.hs:17:8)
  test :: VM.MVector s Int -> Int (bound at rjb.hs:17:3)
In the first argument of `VM.read', namely `a'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: VM.read a 0
```

Edit: The following passes type checking.

```
  test :: VM.MVector (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState IO) Int -> IO (Int)
  test x = VM.read x 0
```

I am guessing that I would be able to mutate the `x` vector as well. So...

Comment: can you please add the actual error?

Comment: `a <- return x` is redundant. That just gives you `x` again.

Comment: @Carsten Added the error.

Comment: It would help if you included your imports.

Comment: If you want to mutate a monadic vector, you _have_ to return a monadic value. That's the whole point of monads: side effects must appear in the type. A function of type `VM.MVector s Int -> Int` is necessarily a constant function.

Comment: Basically you can't do what you're trying to do. You'll probably have to put your entire function in the ST monad. If you show us more of your code we can point out why this is the case.

Comment: @chi So it is like that. I thought that might be the case with Haskell. So does that mean that is is impossible to mutate a mutable vector passed as an argument into a function? What if I used the IO monad? Actually, I just tried it now and it does seem like it would work. Check out the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need some example. Here's a basic commented one, but I'm sure you'll find others in the net if you google a bit.

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as VM

-- This returns a reference to a vector, wrapped in the ST s monad.
test :: ST s (VM.MVector s Int)
test = do
  v <- VM.new 10       -- create vector
  VM.write v 3 2000    -- modify it
  VM.write v 4 3000
  x <- VM.read v 3     -- access it
  VM.write v 4 (x+1)   
  return v             -- return it

-- This instead returns a (wrapped) Int
test2 :: ST s Int
test2 = do
  v <- test            -- call test, which performs the allocation
  VM.read v 4          -- return v[4]

-- This returns a plain pure Int value    
test3 :: Int
test3 = runST test2
```

Note that `runST x` can only be used when the type of `x` is the
polytype `ST s T` where `T` does NOT involve the type variables `s`.
This is how the ST monad achieves referential transparency.

In more simple terms, this means that any "pointer" to allocated memory must never be returned by `runST`. When `runST` returns, every allocation of mutable things can be freed. Hence, a typical `ST s` computation performs `runST` only at the very end, when it's ready to throw away all the mutable data and keep an immutable portion of it. In the example above, the immutable portion was the 4th element (counting from 0, as usual), which is an immutable `Int`.

If you are not familiar with `ST s`, I'd recommend you forget about vectors for the moment, and do some practice with `STRef s Int` (references to `Int`) and `ST`. Any `ST` tutorial would suffice.

Comment: Right, this is what I was looking for. So that is how the type signature for the ST monad looks like. And the mutable vector and the ST monad have the same `s` type. Actually, just what are those `s`'s inside `ST s (VM.MVector s Int)` supposed to be doing apart from preventing me from inadvertently mutating the vector?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic `s` is a dummy type which "taints" all the "pointer-carrying" stuff like `STRef s Int` or `MVector s Int`. Its purpose is to prevent you to return these "pointers" from `runST`, nothing else -- it's just to prove to the compiler that you played by the rules.

Comment: @chi IIRC It is also to prevent you from unsafely interleaving ST actions that are operating on separate chunks of memory. So you can't try and reference a pointer created in block `foo` while within `bar` without running all of `foo` first.